# How to get a right value while of array while i'm adding it to the event thru the loop

Tags: c#, list, events, xamarin

I'm creating an app where user will define an amount of buttons and commands for this button. So... I Have a loop and I'm seting up an "Click" event there, but when I'm trying to use any button I'm always refering to the last element of an array. How can I get a proper command for every button?

```
    namespace TestButton
{
    [Activity(Label = "TestButton", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
            RelativeLayout ly = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.RelativeLayout);
            ObservableCollection<Button> button = new ObservableCollection<Button>();

            int _x = 0, _y = 0;
            int elements = 7;
            string[] commands = new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" };

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (_x != 0)
                    if (_x % 3 == 0)
                    {
                        _y++;
                        _x = 0;
                    }
                button.Add(new Button(this));
                switch (_x)
                {
                    case 0:
                        button[i].SetX((720 / 2 - 150 / 2) - (20 + 150));
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        button[i].SetX(720 / 2 - 150 / 2);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        button[i].SetX((720 / 2 - 150 / 2) + (20 + 150));
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                button[i].SetHeight(150);
                button[i].SetMinimumWidth(10);
                button[i].SetWidth(150);
                button[i].SetY(20 + (_y * 150) + (20 * 1 * _y));
                button[i].SetText("1", TextView.BufferType.Normal);
                button[i].SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.RoundButtonEnabled);
                button[i].Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
                {
                    WriteCommand(commands[i]); //How can I set the "i" command for the button?
                };
                ly.AddView(button[i]);

                elements--;
                if (elements <= 0)
                    break;

                _x++;
            }

        }

        private void WriteCommand(string command)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(command);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just inside the `for` loop do `var i_local = i;` and then use `i_local` in the event handler.

Comment: Well, thanks! It's work's just fine! I have tried before creating a local var, but i was doing it inside the event handler. My bad :) Thanks again!